# How to select only one row per column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have the following schema build_tasks:

```
id|building|queue_time|start_time|completion_time|status|createdAt|updatedAt|baseId|
```

I'm trying to get only the build tasks that have status 'pending', where theres no build_task with the same baseId in status 'in-progress'.

So far, I managed to get a table with all the pending build tasks where there's no in-progress build task. This is the query:

```
select * from (select build_tasks.* from build_tasks
            where status = 'pending') as p
left join in_progress_build_tasks ipbt on p."baseId" = ipbt."baseId"
      where ipbt."baseId" is null;
```

where in_progress_build_tasks is the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "public".in_progress_build_tasks AS
 SELECT DISTINCT build_tasks."baseId"
   FROM build_tasks
  WHERE build_tasks.status = 'in-progress'::enum_build_tasks_status;
```

Which for the table:

```
id |building            |queue_time          |start_time          |completion_time     |status      |createdAt           |updatedAt           |baseId |
---|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|------------|--------------------|--------------------|-------|
7  |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:09:49 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 14:09:49 |2018-02-04 14:09:49 |1      |
10 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:45:07 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 14:45:07 |2018-02-04 14:45:07 |1      |
6  |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:07:32 |2018-02-04 14:07:58 |2018-02-04 14:08:08 |in-progress |2018-02-04 14:07:32 |2018-02-04 14:08:09 |1      |
12 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:46:04 |2018-02-04 14:46:04 |2018-02-04 14:46:04 |successful  |2018-02-04 14:46:04 |2018-02-04 14:58:28 |2      |
8  |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:10:29 |2018-02-04 14:10:29 |2018-02-04 14:10:39 |successful  |2018-02-04 14:10:29 |2018-02-04 14:10:39 |2      |
9  |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |2      |
11 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |2      |
13 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |3      |
15 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |3      |
14 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |                    |                    |pending     |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |3      |
```

Gives me the output:

```
id |building            |queue_time          |start_time |completion_time |status  |createdAt           |updatedAt           |baseId |baseId |
---|--------------------|--------------------|-----------|----------------|--------|--------------------|--------------------|-------|-------|
9  |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |           |                |pending |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |2018-02-04 14:11:38 |2      |       |
11 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |           |                |pending |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |2018-02-04 14:45:14 |2      |       |
13 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |           |                |pending |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |2018-02-04 15:11:16 |3      |       |
14 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |           |                |pending |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |2018-02-04 15:11:18 |3      |       |
15 |resource01_refinery |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |           |                |pending |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |2018-02-04 15:11:19 |3      |       |
```

How can I reduce the results to only 1 row per base_id, selected based on the lowest queue_time?

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what you want for output.  But if you want to identify the base ids that meet your conditions, you can use aggregation:

```
select bt.baseid
from build_tasks bt
group by bt.baseid
having sum( (bt.status = 'pending'::enum_build_tasks_status)::int) > 0 and
       sum( (bt.status = 'in-progress'::enum_build_tasks_status)::int) = 0 ;
```

I am not sure what else you want in the output.  Likely you can get what you want using aggregation.  Alternatively, a `join`, `in`, or `exists` can get what you want.

However, you do not a need a view to accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: I want the same output I'm already getting, BUT only 1 row per baseId, and select that row based on the lowest completion time (for that base id)

Answer (score 0):

You may apply `DISTINCT ON (baseId)`  above your output.

```
SELECT * FROM
(

SELECT DISTINCT ON (baseId)  youroutput.*
  FROM youroutput ORDER BY baseId,updatedAt
) as a;
```